# how to benchmark the kafka spark-streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have to perform the benchmarking of spark streaming processing. My process gets pulls messages from the kafka, process and loads into ElasticSearch. The upstream generates 100k records per second. So I would like to calculate how many messages processed in 1 second and the latency time. Is there any tools available to monitor this or is there any process to calculate this.

Comment: You can check the spark ui of your job. It's very detailed.

Comment: when you say 'benchmark', what metrics do you want to obtain?

Comment: i want how many messages are processed per second

Comment: As @z-star said, the UI has that info. Let the job run long enough to observe the long-term behaviour of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Spark UI can help you,providing the necessary details you need.
By default, the spark ui is available on  http://:4040 in a web browser(For a single spark Context).
For the help,you can use this link: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the Spark UI, which is useful for determining the rate of processing of your data, you can also use third-party tools like [spark-perf](https://github.com/databricks/spark-perf) to perform load testing on your cluster and obtain benchmark data in that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone should try Yahoo's streaming-benchmarks, I found databricks use that tool to do benchmark between spark streaming and flink.

https://github.com/yahoo/streaming-benchmarks
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/11/benchmarking-structured-streaming-on-databricks-runtime-against-state-of-the-art-streaming-systems.html